# Solr 4.6.1 Admin UI doesn't work in IE9

Tags: solr, internet-explorer-9

I am not able to access Solr admin page in IE9. I am using solr 4.6.1. I am getting an alert "There is no core exists with ~index". Can somebody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Are you able to access Solr admin page in other browsers (like chrome, firefox) ?

Comment: yes. I am able to access in chrome and firefox.